# Where to define CSS files in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Defining custom css for a class got me confused.

The React-Bootstrap documentation says, you can define a custom non-bootstrap style  by using `bsClass`.

But, here are my doubts:-

1. Do we need to include the custom stylesheet link in the entry html page?
2. If no, then how is node environment, able to recognise where are the css files located?

Comment: use webpack ...

Comment: I have webpack, That doesn't answer the question though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how is node environment able to recognize where are the css files located?

You need to add it to your page manually.

One approach (if you use `webpack` and have `css-loader` plugin installed, which is by default for `react-create-app`) is to include your .css file inside a component that needs specific stylesheet:

```
import './mystylesheet.css'
```

So your component will look something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './mystylesheet.css'

export default function MyCustomButton(props) {
  return <Button bsClass="my-custom-class">My button</Button>
}
```

Comment: Neatly explained! Thanks :D